# Telegram bot Delete a sticker set

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot, telegram-api

You can create a new sticker set owned by your bot and the user with `createNewStickerSet` method. I was wondering if you can delete the sticker set too because I can't find any method specifying that in the wiki

Answer (score 0):

[Detete](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#deletestickerfromset) all the stickers out of the pack so it's just a dead pack, it will disappear after about an hour